# how back to the main activity in android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, activity-finish, onbackpressed

I have a `MainActivity` "A", which have a button that launch activity "B", and activity "B" have another button that launch activity "C". In the activities B and C, both have `onBackPressed()` method, which appears an `AlertDialog` asking if the user wants to return to `MainActivity`. If they press yes, the program should show MainActiviy.

The question is: in activity B, i have not problem, simply call the `finish()` method, and `MainActivity` appears, but the problem is in activity C, if i call a `finish()` method, the program is back to activity B. How back to `MainActivity` from activity C??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this on you onBackPressed:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

this clears the activity stack and opens your main activity. No matter which activity you are, you will always go back to the main activity and all other activities are removed from the stack.

Comment: this is working, but the transition between activities is not smooth

Answer (score 3):

Use the following in your manifest file for the activity B and C:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityB"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>
<activity android:name=".ActivityC"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try ActivityCompat.finishAffinity and start MainActivity at your Activity C.