# Android - How do I switch between 1st and 3rd activities?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a 1st and a 3rd activity. I wish to push a button on the 3rd activity and it finishes the 3rd and 2nd activity switching all the way back to the 1st activity(it's the MainActivity might I add). In other words, is there a way to finish automaticly the call stack of activities to a specific activity?

Comment: There is not, but if you don't want a flow where pressing back leads to C>B>A then you can `finish()` activity B when you are launching activity C.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method startActivityForResult() to start your activity.

You need to call method setResult() when you finish the activity.

And override method onActivityResult() to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, seems 2 methods can solve this.

Assuming Activities: A -> B -> C, and all alive in the same stack.

1) Use android:launchMode="singleTask" for Activity A. When C calls A, A starts and both B & C finish.

2) When starting A, adding flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have to pass any data to the main activity, i guess this is what you are looking for: [how back to the main activity in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33251483/887692)

execute this code at the button click in your 3rd activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

this code clears your activity stack and reopens your main activity.